# Setting angular validators in link function scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add validators to my angular app. I can set them fine on the input but once I try to bind values to the directive it's not working.

```
directives.directive('text', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: '^parentForm',
    scope: {
      formField: "=",
      modelField: "=",
      onChange: '&',
      isDisabled: '=',
      isRequired: '=',
      isGeneric: '=',
      inputId: '@',
      inputPlaceholder: '=',
      maxlength: '=',
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'text.html',
    link: genericLinkFx()
  };
});
```

the `genericLinkFx` is:

```
var genericLinkFx = function(manipulator) {

  return function(scope, element, attrs, snGenericForm) {

    scope.cls = attrs.cls;

    if (angular.isDefined(scope.isRequired)) {
      scope.required = scope.isRequired;
    } else if (!scope.formField.metadata.can_be_blank) {
      scope.required = true      
    } else {
      scope.required = false;
    };

    if (scope.formField.metadata.validators.length > 0) {
      _.each(scope.formField.metadata.validators, function(validator) {
        switch (validator.type) {
          case 'RegexValidator':
            scope.pattern = '/' + validator.regex + '/';
            break;
          case 'MaxLengthValidator':
            scope.maxlength = validator.limit_value;
            break;
          case 'MinLengthValidator': 
            scope.minlength = validator.limit_value;
            break;
        } 
      })
    };
   }
  }

};
```

the template is:

```
<input type="text" id="{{ inputId }}" class="{{ cls }}" ng-model="modelField"
    ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-required="required"
    placeholder="{{ inputPlaceholder }}" 
    ng-maxlength="maxlength">
    {{ maxlength }}, {{ pattern }}
</input>
```

What's frustrating is that I can see {{ maxlength }} being set but I can't use it. If I hardcode `ng-maxlength="10"` it works. However, `ng-maxlength=maxlength` does not work as intended

Comment: Dont you need to interpolate it ? `ng-maxlength="{{maxlength}}">` and 2-way binding should be `maxlength="maxlength"` and not `ng-maxlength` typo?

Comment: @PSL interpolation works if I add maxlength="10" to the html where the directive is being used. However I'd rather be able to set this info in the directive and not in the controller.

Comment: Are you using built in ng-maxlength or intend to use 2 way bound maxlength? They both are 2 different things. i,e <input ... maxlength="maxlength">

Comment: @PSL hoping to use built in ng-maxlength and set it once but open to suggestions

Comment: What is your issue then? your current issue seems to be because of _typo_

Comment: @PSL my issue is that I can't set maxlength in the link function, only in the HTML.

Comment: You would need to do `ng-maxlength="{{maxlength}}" maxlength="maxlength"` because if you want to take advantage of ng-maxlength with a 2 way bound maxlength property you need both, unless i understand your question wrongly. Do you have a demo in a plunker?

Comment: @PSL interesting, so need to define a custom directive...

Comment: Not a custom directive, you already have a 2-way bound property called `maxlength`

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> if you want to take advantage of ng-maxlength with a 2 way bound maxlength property you need both:

`ng-maxlength="{{maxlength}}" maxlength="maxlength"`

the directive and the HTML attribute.